# Passing data through modal segue: [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to pass dogData from my ViewController to PetViewController (through a modal segue). That said, for some reason when I attempt to pass the dogData (NSMutableArray), I get this error:

> [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Any idea why this might be? See code below (hope this is enough info, tried to trim it).

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dogData;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
 NSMutableDictionary *viewParamsDogs = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParamsDogs setValue:@"mydogs" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParamsDogs success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


      self.dogData = [responseObject mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"This is the dog photo data %@", self.dogData);

        [operation responseString];


        NSDictionary *dic = [responseObject valueForKey: @"field_pet_photo_path"];
                             NSArray *arr = [dic valueForKey: @"und"];
                             NSDictionary *dic2= [arr objectAtIndex : 0];
       NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dic2 valueForKey: @"safe_value"]];


        NSMutableCharacterSet *characterSetToTrim = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()\""];
        [characterSetToTrim formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        path = [path stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:characterSetToTrim];



  if([path length]>0) {



      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

      NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
      self.dogimageView.image = image;


        } else {

            NSString *ImageURL = @"http://url.ca/paw.png";
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
            self.dogimageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
      }


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];



        - (IBAction)openPetProfile:(id)sender {

            PetViewController *petProfile = [[PetViewController alloc] init];
            petProfile.petSubDetail = self.dogData;
            [self presentViewController:petProfile animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
```

**PetViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *petSubDetail;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *petName;
```

**PetViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

      self.petName.text = [self.petSubDetail valueForKey:@"petname"];


}
```

**Data output:**

```
  "field_petname" =         {
        und =             (
                            {
                format = "<null>";
                "safe_value" = Pebbles;
                value = Pebbles;
            }
        );
    };
```

Comment: Why are you calling `valueForKey:`` on an array? This gives you back another array.

Comment: @rmaddy should I be using objectForKey (I thought I used this for dictionaries)? Sorry for the newb Q. What should it be instead?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want out of the array. You need to clarify what is in the array. You are right the `objectForKey` is for dictionaries. You seem to want some title out of the array. But where in the array is the title that you want?

Comment: What does your dogData array contains. If it contains a dictionary then try NSDictionary *temp = [self.petSubDetail objectAtIndex:0]; and then self.petName.text = [temp valueForKey:@"title"];

Comment: @rmaddy See updated code above - added output structure (see title).

Comment: You posted some XML. Nothing about the code you posted appears to deal with that XML. Update your question with the output of `self.petSubDetail`.

Comment: @rmaddy See data output above :)

Comment: Your output is showing a dictionary but the variable is declared as an `NSMutableArray`. That doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like,

```
 NSdictionary *dict =  [self.petSubDetail objectForKey:@"field_petname"];
 NSArray *arr = [dict objectForKey:@"und"];
 NSdictionary *dict1 = [arr objectAtIndex : 0];
 self.petName.text = [dict1  valueForKey:@"value"];
```

where you need `"` in key use `\"` 
hope this will help :)

Comment: This line doesnt work:   NSDictionary *dict =  [self.petSubDetail objectForKey:@"field_petname"]; The error is: No visible @interface for NSMutableArray declares the selector objectForKey